# Converting a query to handle key value columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help updating this query:

```
$query = sprintf(
   "SELECT 
        lat, 
        lng, 
        ( 
            3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
                         cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                         cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + 
                         sin( radians('%s') ) * 
                         sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                       ) 
        ) AS distance 
    FROM 
        markers 
    HAVING 
        distance < '%s' 
    ORDER BY 
        distance LIMIT 0 , 20"
```

With a table structure like:

```
lat        | lng
23.0324234 | -103.0324234
```

To a query that I can grab `shipping_lat` and `shipping_long` from a key, value column structure in a table like this:

```
meta_key      | meta_value
shipping_lat  | 23.0324234
shipping_long | -103.0324234
```

Comment: You might also want to look into MySQL's [GIS extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/gis-introduction.html).

Comment: @dcolumbus we do expect for you to put effort in. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following as a subquery that you join to your main query (or similar)?

```sql
SELECT t1.meta_value AS lat, t2.meta_value AS lng
FROM   meta_table t1 JOIN meta_table t2
WHERE  t1.meta_key = 'shipping_lat'
   AND t2.meta_key = 'shipping_long'
```

That is:

```sql
SELECT 
    lat, 
    lng, 
    ( 
        3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
                     cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                     cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + 
                     sin( radians('%s') ) * 
                     sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                   ) 
    ) AS distance 
FROM 
    markers JOIN (
      SELECT t1.meta_value AS lat, t2.meta_value AS lng
      FROM   meta_table t1 JOIN meta_table t2
      WHERE  t1.meta_key = 'shipping_lat'
         AND t2.meta_key = 'shipping_long'
    ) AS t
HAVING 
    distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY 
    distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

One could avoid the subquery by directly joining `meta_table` to `markers` twice (on the relevant `meta_key`s) and then referencing the `meta_value`s directly instead of `lat` and `lng`, but I thought the above would be more readable and easier to follow.  However, for completeness:

```sql
SELECT 
    lat.meta_value, 
    lng.meta_value, 
    ( 
        3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * 
                     cos( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) * 
                     cos( radians( lng.meta_value ) - radians('%s') ) + 
                     sin( radians('%s') ) * 
                     sin( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) 
                   ) 
    ) AS distance 
FROM 
    markers
      JOIN meta_table lat ON lat.meta_key = 'shipping_lat'
      JOIN meta_table lng ON lng.meta_key = 'shipping_long'
HAVING 
    distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY 
    distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Comment: I see where you're going with the query above, but I'm unsure of how to combine the two. You see, the function in the middle takes care of the radius for the lat and lng params.

Comment: @dcolumbus: `... FROM markers JOIN ( <query above> ) AS t ...`

Comment: Would you be so kind as to just join them here in your answer? Queries are so specific that I'm going to be running around trying to locate an issue if there is one.

Comment: For example, I'm getting the error `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: @dcolumbus: See my edit, above.